# Wrong parameter in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

I have a php file that acts as an abstraction between a program and my database. I tried getting it to return a value and I got this error:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': USERNAME
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1' at line 2
```

The entire code for my API is this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require 'UHCauth.php';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_serv;dbname=$mysql_db", 
$mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

if(isset($_GET['USERNAME'])) {
    $USERNAME = $_GET['USERNAME'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table
        WHERE USERNAME = : USERNAME
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1"
    );
    $stmt->execute(array('USERNAME' => $USERNAME));

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row);
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table
        ORDER BY
            McVersion DESC,
            ModVersion DESC
        LIMIT 1"
    );
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row);
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

It is supposed to take a username and return the row for that username in JSON format. This code has worked before for a different project and now it's decided not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
 WHERE USERNAME = : USERNAME
                   ^--//dont make sapce here
```

to

```
 WHERE USERNAME = :USERNAME
```

Comment: Yep. That fixed my problem. No idea how that space snuck in there.